# Matching a list of IDs with their corresponding objects

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist

I've got a `Dictionary<int BossID, string BossName> ListOfBosses` and `Dictionary<String EmpName, int BossID> ListOfEmps` . Of course, Match the BossID to the Boss and return 'Dictionary WhoIsMyBoss'.

I have no idea where to start in Java.

As far as the two lists go, we'll assume there is going be a one to many ratio of Bosses to Emps.  And the BossIDs are incremental from 1-n.

I figure I would do the following in my illiterate Java. . .

```
Dictionary<BossName, EmpName> WhoIsMyBoss;
ArrayList<Integer> AnotherListOfBosses;
private int Boss;
for (String EmpName: ListOfEmps)
        Boss = ListOfEmps.get(EmpName)
        WhoIsMyBoss.put(ListofBosses(Boss) , EmpName);
        AnotherListOfBosses.add(Boss);
}
for(int Boss: AnotherListOfBosses)
{
     ListOfBosses.remove(Boss)
}
```

That should leave me a list of Bosses and Employees and a
a ListOfBosses with no corresponding Employees hopefully.

How does that look? Is Dictionary the correct Collection to use? Any improvements would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kilian Foth mentioned, you should use Map instead of `Dictionary`. Additionally in Java the convention is to start variable names with a lowercase and classname uppercase letter.

You said that the names are strings and the IDs integers.

```
public class BossExample {
  // Key: Boss-ID, Value: Boss name
  private Map<Integer, String> mapOfBosses = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

  // Key: Emp name, Value: Boss-ID
  private Map<String, Integer> mapOfEmps = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

  // Constructor fills the maps
  public BossExample() {
    // ...
  }

  // Returns a mapping from Emp name to Boss name
  public Map<String, String> getEmpToBossMap() {
    final Map<String, String> empToBossMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // Iterate through mapOfEmps via entrySet giving you key and value 
    // at the same time
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> empEntry : mapOfEmps.entrySet()) {
      // Put the Emp name as key and the retrieved Boss name as a value into 
      // the result map.
      empToBossMap.put(empEntry.getKey(), mapOfBosses.get(empEntry.getValue()));
    }

    return empToBossMap;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure what that for loop is doing.  Gonna have to look up the Map interface. . .

Comment: Ah, Durrr.  For every entry in set of entries in mapOfEmps.

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary` is obsolete, so you should use some kind of `Map` instead (usually a `HashMap`). Also, calling your variables `...List` is very misleading, since there is an extremely common Collections type called `List`, and it does something different (it represents ordering, but not mapping), so you should probably call your variables `...map` as well.

Since one boss can have several employees, the mapping should be from employee to boss, and not the other way round (the key is always named first). The corresponding `put` is also the wrong way.

There are also some other issues with missing declarations and a missing `get()`, but the compiler should set you straight there.

Comment: I guess you mean Map<Employee, Boss> instead of surfasb's mapping from boss to employee.

Comment: Awesome. I just noticed the Dictionary as I started typing it into Eclipse and started reading the tool tip. I should be able to figure out the declarations though. Yeah, those aren't the real names.  I just put them there to make it easier for me to read and type out.

Answer (score 1):

> Any improvements would be greatly appreciated.

You need to learn the the Java style rules for identifiers.

- Class names are camel case starting with an uppercase character.
- Method names, and names of variables, parameters and attributes ate camel case starting with a lower case character.
- Package names are all lowercase
- Constant (e.g. `static final` variables) names are all uppercase with underscores as name separators.